# Must a floated div containing an image have a width?

Tags: css

I'm exploring responsive design and learning more about CSS and was delighted to discover that if I place an image inside a div and float it, I don't need to assign the div a width. Apparently, it automatically assumes the width of the enclosed image. (I should also point out that I've stripped the width and height attributes out of all my images.)

I'm working on a Mac, and it works beautifully with Chrome, Safari, Firefox and Opera at various screen sizes. (Actually, I'm having a few problems with Firefox, but the floats are working fine.)

However, some sources say you should always assign a width to a floated div. So, just to make sure I know what I'm getting into, can anyone give me some specific reasons I should assign widths to these divs? I assume defined widths might be required by some older browsers. Also, I haven't tested my pages in Internet Explorer yet.

Comment: yes there is a reason you should assign a width unless the divs only contain an image in which case you should not. but with other content it keeps the content showing instead of making the display value 0

Comment: _"However, some sources say you should always assign a width to a floated div."_ Please cite the source. I've never heard of this requirement myself. It's a good practice to assign a width and height to an image, as it helps prevent the page from jumping when loading, but I've never heard this wrt floats.

Comment: http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/introduction15.htm. Floated elements shrink to fit so if you have a block element that needs to always be a minimum width for the layout, you don't want to rely on all browsers to handle your floated element contents the same. Also, if the only content of your floated div is an image, just float the image. They have explicit width so they are the exception.

Comment: @ j08691 - The source is http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/ which says "“You should always set a width on floated items." But, judging by what I've read here, I don't need to apply a width to divs that contain images. I should also explain that not all of my images are contained in divs. However, I often put them inside divs so I can add extra styling. Of course, images accompanied by captions also require divs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of things, setting a specific width on a floated element really just helps you to control how the element is sized. From the article I'm linking below, when there isn't a width set on a floated element, it will collapse down to the width of the widest item inside, which could be as small as a single width. By adding a specific width we can make sure that the floated element looks/behaves as you intended it!

http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/introduction.htm

Cheers

Comment: @ Sean William Washington - Ah, the article you linked to says the same thing: "You should always set a width on floated items (except if applied directly to an image - which has implicit width). W3C's Cascading Style Sheets, level 2, CSS2 Specifications states:

'A floated box must have an explicit width...'"

But it sounds like the author may have erred. Instead of saying a floated box MUST have an explicit width, he should have added "unless it contains an image."

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom You're probably right. I know that personally, I only set an explicit width on a floated element if I know that it needs a specific width for aesthetic purposes. I think it may be one of those things where if something's broken and you're going nuts trying to debug, slap a width on it to see if that fixes your problem!